# pass a variable value from if statement to outside of if/else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need update my 'calculated_price' value live when user check one of my checkboxes. alert() works and calculate currectly but I don't know why it just display '0' and not be change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Global Configurations.
    var calculated_price = 0;
    var final_price = "قیمت نهایی برابر است با " + calculated_price + " تومان ";

    // Menu Items.
    var cbSelector = $("[name='cb[]']");
    cbSelector.change(function () {
        if (this.checked){
            var currentCBSelected = $(this);
            var currentCBValue = parseInt(currentCBSelected.val());

            var previousNSelected = $(this).prev("input");
            var previousNValue = parseInt(previousNSelected.val());

            previousNSelected.css("visibility","visible");

            calculated_price += currentCBValue * previousNValue;
        }
        else {
            // Do somethings.
        }

    });

    // Calculated Price.
    $("#calculated_price").html(final_price);

});
```

here is my index.html file that will be check checkboxes to show number inputs that their values can be change (so calculated_price must be change)

```
    <!-- Page Logo -->
    <div>
        <a href="#time_picker"><img id="page_logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Time Picker -->
    <div id="time_picker">
        <div id="time_picker_in">
            <p>زمان ورود: </p>
        </div>
        <div id="time_picker_out">
            <p>زمان خروج: </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu Items -->
    <div>
        <ul id="menu_items">
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="12000" />
                <label for="text1">چای و ساید کیک</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="5000" />
                <label for="text2">چای سیاه</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="7000" />
                <label for="text3">چای سبز</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="7000" />
                <label for="text4">چای و خرما</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="7000" />
                <label for="text5">چای و نبات</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="7000" />
                <label for="text6">چای و دارچین</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="15000" />
                <label for="text7">آبمیوه(پرتقال،هندوانه،طالبی)</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="15000" />
                <label for="text8">هات چاکلت</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="15000" />
                <label for="text9">نسکافه</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="15000" />
                <label for="text10">کاپوچینو</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="15000" />
                <label for="text11">شکلات گلاسه</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="15000" />
                <label for="text12">سالاد روز</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="10000" />
                <label for="text13">سیب زمینی</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="15000" />
                <label for="text14">غذای روز کودک</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" name="n[]" value="1" class="num_input"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="10000" />
                <label for="text15">بستنی(12 اسکوپ)</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- White Space -->
    <div id="white_space"></div>

    <!-- Calculated Price -->
    <div id="calculated_price"></div>
```

Comment: add your html  code too

Comment: You don't seem to ever display the value after you calculate it.  If you only ever display the initial value of 0 and never update the display then it's only ever going to show 0.

Comment: you need to add this **$("#calculated_price").html(final_price);** inside the **change**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you expect changes to the calculated_price variable to automatically reflect in your final_price string, but it doesn't work that way.  Every time the calculated_price variable changes, you have to insert it into your final_price string, and then update the html again.

Change this line:

```
var final_price = "قیمت نهایی برابر است با " + calculated_price + " تومان ";
```

to:

```
var final_price = "قیمت نهایی برابر است با {calc} تومان ";
```

Add this line at the end of your if statement:

```
$("#calculated_price").html(final_price.replace("{calc}", calculated_price.toString());
```

And change your last line to:

```
$("#calculated_price").html(final_price.replace("{calc}", calculated_price.toString());
```

Comment: Could you explain what you actually changed? And what those changes do?

Comment: Done.  I know its perhaps not the best solution, but I think its one that he should be able to easily understand.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with the curly bracket syntax in Javascript, but I'm not a javascript developer either. I'm not sure how common knowledge it is, but in PHP basically the change you made there wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: There is nothing special about the curly brackets in this case.  Its just a simple way to insert the calculated price into the middle of the string.

Comment: Are you familiar with PHP curly bracket (complex expression) syntax? I'm just wondering if it's the same syntax. Also, why do you use it in the last 2 lines of code you mentioned? Couldn't you just put the variable itself there?

Comment: I have little experience with php.  This is just a simple string replace. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: I underestod , thanks, but see my html code also...I need be able to checkbox have a number and calculated_price show currentCBValue*previousNValue! Your answer works but what about if I want change input number than 1 to other numbers??!

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Perhaps you could make a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) with a simplified version of your code, and then show how you want to change it?

Comment: I will have 2 time picker and 15 checkbox that when you check a checkbox,you can add a number in input (type is number) ... now I want : calculated_price show live the currentCBValue*previousNValue live